# Is ES module import from another module worthwhile for a single value?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I understand that ES modules are loaded only once in the following example. What is the best approach when only one, or a few, simple variables are needed?

**mod1.js**

```js
export class One {

  static android = navigator.userAgent.includes('Android');
  // --- more code
}
```

**mod2.js**

```js
import {One} from './mod1.js';

export class Two {
  
  // needs only One.android
  // --- more code
}
```

**background.js**

```js
import {One} from './mod1.js';
import {Two} from './mod2.js';

// --- more code
```

Since `background.js` imports both modules, and modules are loaded only once, is it worthwhile to import `mod1.js` into `mod2.js` only for one variables? Or would it better to redefine the variable? e.g.

**mod2.js**

```js
export class Two {
  
  static android = navigator.userAgent.includes('Android');
  // --- more code
}
```

Comment: Why would you *not* `import` it? Modules exist to reduce repetition, so use them, I guess?

Comment: Well if `Two` wants to reference `One`, then it must import it, otherwise it won't be available in scope

Comment: You could (possibly should) of course put `export const android = …` in a *third* module and import that in both *mod1.js* and *mod2.js*

Answer (score 1):

Just stick with importing your modules since it's cleaner and respects the DRY principle. Happy coding!